# how do i convert hundreds of CSS file to SCSS files?

Tags: css, ruby, html, sass

I have existing project which is being used 300 css files and now the requirement is to convert it from css to SCSS.

Requesting your help on this, if some one shed some light it will be great full..

**Online Tools**

- http://css2sass.herokuapp.com/

i have tried converting through online but it will lag too many hours to do, so finding some good idea / suggestion which can be done with script.

Thanks !!

Comment: SCSS is a superset of CSS. Your CSS can already be read as SCSS.

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2):

You could use sass-convert from the [sass](https://github.com/sass/sass) gem :

```
sass-convert -R my_css_dir --from css --to scss
```

To convert every `.css` file inside `my_css_dir`

Note: It seems that you need sass 3.4.22. See [here](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1827) and [there](https://github.com/sass/sass/commit/27e12f35d3701f882ec85f6bbbf303d2742e1682).

Comment: The npm link is a bit misleading – `sass-convert` comes with the Sass gem. There's no need to install a Node.js package.

Comment: Iam getting the below error.. 


C:\xampp\htdocs\MYFOLDER\projects\css-converter>sass-convert -R css --from css --to scss
    convert css/styles-1.css
     create css/styles-1.scss

NoMethodError: undefined method `read' for "css/styles-1.css":String
  Use --trace for backtrace.

Comment: No need for any parameter after `--to scss`. The parameter after `-R` should be the name of the **directory** inside which you have all your `.css` files

Comment: Iam doing like this from cmd -> sass-convert -R css-folder --from css --to scss

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129793/discussion-between-yoo-and-eric-duminil).

Answer (score 1):

Ruby gem `sass` contains `sass-converter` utility, so you can use them.

Docs:

> The sass-convert executable converts between CSS, Sass, and SCSS. When
>   converting from CSS to Sass or SCSS, nesting is applied where
>   appropriate. See sass-convert --help for further information and
>   options.

```
bundle exec sass-convert ...
```

See `sass-convert --help` for further information and options.

[Source file](https://github.com/sass/sass/blob/master/lib/sass/exec/sass_convert.rb) from github. [Readme](https://github.com/sass/sass/blob/master/README.md).

[Gem repository](https://github.com/sass/sass).